# Code coverage issue RecordType.Name required

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, code

I am trying to fetch the RecordType.Name in a list, but my list doesn't has the value displayed.
Please find below the block of code and the list 'clist' where I need the RecordType.Name
This is in a test class.

```
Id RecordTypeIdCase = Schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Core eG@r Case RecType').getRecordTypeId();
case cs = new case (Type='Warranty Support',EmailContactDealer__c='test@gmail.com', Origin='RENAULT SITE', AccountId=Acc.Id, ContactId=Acc.PersoncontactId, Status='New', Description='Trigger test clas', CountryCase__c='Argentina',RecordTypeid = RecordTypeIdCase);
insert cs;
List<RecordType> RTList = [SELECT Id, Name,DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE Id = :RecordTypeIdCase];
            System.debug('$&$&$& RecordType RT:' + RTList);
            System.debug('$&$&$& Case ID:' + cs.Id);
            System.debug('$&$&$& Case RTID:' + cs.RecordTypeid);
            System.debug('$&$&$& Case RT:' + cs.RecordType.DeveloperName);
      
      List<Case> cList = [SELECT Id,Type,RecordTypeid,RecordType.Name FROM Case WHERE Type = 'Warranty Support' AND RecordType.Name = 'Core eG@r Case RecType'];
System.assertEquals(cList.size(), 1);
```

Comment: This is a very common problem that is asked here a lot, so I've created a new [overview and canonical question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318730/why-cant-i-see-related-data-in-my-apex-or-why-are-related-records-showing-up-a/318731#318731). In short, you _always must query relationship data in Apex_. That's why your `cs.RecordType.DeveloperName` is null. Is that your question, or are you. asking about something related to `cList` itself?

Comment: Not exactly clear what is the issue. 
But as general tip - for debugging purpose, you can remove the filtering in the query for cList and then print the values it gets.
See what are the values and then try to figure why those aren't the values that you expect.