# Why can't I see related data in my Apex, or why are related records showing up as `null`?

Tags: apex, relationships, canonical-qa

*This is a **canonical question and answer** developed by the community to help address common questions. If you've been directed here, or your question has been closed as a duplicate, please look through the resources here and use them to shape more specific questions. To browse all canonical questions and answers, navigate to the [`canonical-qa`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa) tag.*

*This question and answer is owned by the community! If you can improve it and make it more useful, you're welcome to edit it.*

I am building a trigger, a unit test, or other Apex code. I'm working with sObject records, and trying to access related record information. For example, I might have a structure like this:

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
insert a;

Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name = 'Donation', AccountId = a.Id);
insert o;

System.assertEquals(o.Account.Name, 'Test', 'Correct Account associated'); // Assertion fails!
```

Or, in a trigger, I might be aiming for something like this:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.Account.Name == 'Test') {
            // Take some action here
        }
     }
}
```

Why doesn't this work? Why am I getting `null` values, or `NullPointerException`s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everywhere in Apex, it is a fact that *you must query relationship data you wish to reference*.

- When you insert a record, the only field in your object that is modified by the Apex runtime is the `Id`: no relationship data is populated, not even to metadata objects like `RecordType`, and not even to other sObjects you're working with in your local code unit. You must re-query to obtain related record information.
- When you receive an object from a trigger context variable, you are not provided with any related-record data. You must perform a query to obtain that data. *Note that cross-object formula fields in your trigger context variable will be populated.*

If you fail to do so and traverse a relationship, you will get back a `null` value. If you write code that attempts to act on the returned value, you risk a `NullPointerException`, for example,

```
if (o.Account.Name.startsWith('HIGH')) {
```

### Examples

#### General Apex

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
insert a;

Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name = 'Donation', AccountId = a.Id);
insert o;

o = [SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :o.Id];

System.assertEquals(o.Account.Name, 'Test', 'Correct Account associated'); // Assertion passes!
```

We re-query the inserted object to acquire the desired relationship data, and here, the assertion passed.

#### Apex Triggers

There are slightly different patterns that may be applied in `before` and `after` triggers. Starting with an `after` trigger, as above, we'd rebuild the trigger something like this:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]) {
        if (c.Account.Name == 'Test') {
            // Take some action here
        }
     }
}
```

We simply replace iteration over `Trigger.new` (and similar structures) with iteration over a query, which sources relationship data as well as other required fields and which is limited to the trigger context set.

In a `before insert` context, we can't do this, because our trigger context variables are not yet committed to the database and hence cannot be queried. In this context, we must query the related records directly, using collections like `Set<Id>` and `Map<Id, sObject>` to bulkify the code and connect our trigger context variables with queried related records:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.AccountId != null) {
            accountIds.add(a.AccountId);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>(
        [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]
    );
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.AccountId != null && accountMap.get(c.AccountId).Name == 'Test') {
            // Take some action here
        }
     }
}
```

Note that in this case we must do additional work to guard against `null` relationships.