# Issue with after update trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, controller, validation, after-trigger

I have a trigger which creates new Cust_Alert_record when Policy__c record is updated.

Below is my trigger:

```
trigger AlertTextforContact on Policy__c (after update) {
    List<Cust_Alert__c> CustAlertList = new List<Cust_Alert__c>();

    for(Policy__c pol : trigger.new) {
        if(pol.Account_Role__r.role_name__c.contains('Duplicate') || pol.Account_Role__r.role_name__c.contains('Original')) {
            
            Cust_Alert__c custalert = new Cust_Alert__c(
                Contact__c = pol.Account_Role__r.Contact__c,
                Status__c = 'Active'
            );
            CustAlertList.add(custalert);
        }
    }

    insert CustAlertList;
}
```

I have two issues with my code above

1. From line 5 (if statement) which checks for given **Duplicate** and **Original** keywords, I am getting Null pointer exception error even though Account_role__r.role_name__c has the given values.
2. From line 8, Account_Role__r.Contact__c id not getting updated to Contact__c field. Account_Role__c is the parent and Account_Role__r.Contact__c is the grandparent of the Policy__c record.

Can anyone please suggest any changes to the above code so that I can get this done. Thanks!

Comment: if your org is on w21, try like this (Safe navigation operator) - 
pol?.Account_Role__r?.role_name__c?.contains('Duplicate')

Comment: Data for related records is not available in trigger context variables, and needs to be queried. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318730/why-cant-i-see-related-data-in-my-apex-or-why-are-related-records-showing-up-a goes into more detail.

Comment: No @YsrShk, that didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

Trigger.new does not contain the parent field values and you are trying to access directly from it. This is the reason you are getting the null pointer exception while using with **contains** method.

You need to modify the code in such a way that you can access the parent field values. The approach is:-

1. Create a set to store the Account_Role__c id by running a for loop
   on trigger.new.
2. Then query the Account Role object record in a map.
3. You can access the parent field value from map inside the loop.

   ```
    trigger AlertTextforContact on Policy__c (after update) {
    List<Cust_Alert__c> CustAlertList = new List<Cust_Alert__c>();


   set<Id> accountRoleId = new set<id>();
   for(Policy__c pol : trigger.new) {
       if(pol.Account_Role__c!=null) {
           accountRoleId.add(pol.Account_Role__c);
       }
   }
   Map<id,Account_Role__c> mapOfIdWithAccountRole = new Map<id,Account_Role__c>([select role_name__c,Contact__c from Account_Role__c where id=:accountRoleId]);

   for(Policy__c pol : trigger.new) {
       if(mapOfIdWithAccountRole.get(pol.Account_Role__c)?.role_name__c?.contains('Duplicate') || mapOfIdWithAccountRole.get(pol.Account_Role__c)?.role_name__c?..contains('Original')) {

           Cust_Alert__c custalert = new Cust_Alert__c(
               Contact__c = mapOfIdWithAccountRole.get(pol.Account_Role__c)?.Contact__c,
               Status__c = 'Active'
           );
           CustAlertList.add(custalert);
       }
   }

   insert CustAlertList;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Sanket. This did work. However, every time when I update the policy record, cust_alert__c record is getting created. Is there any way  I can restrict this to only one record. Please suggest

Comment: I believe this should be separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Records fetch by trigger.new contain fields of that record only, it doesn't fetch related record. To fetch role_name__c field of Account_Role__c, you need to query that record once again.

```
trigger AlertTextforContact on Policy__c (after update) {
    List<Cust_Alert__c> CustAlertList = new List<Cust_Alert__c>();

    List<Id> accRoleIDList = new List<Id>();

    for(Policy__c pol : trigger.new) {
        accRoleIDList.add(pol.Account_Role__c);
    }

    List<Account_Role__c> accRoleList = [Select ID,Contact__c,role_name__c from Account_Role__c where ID in :accRoleIDList];

    Map<Id, Account_Role__c> accRoleMap = new Map<Id, Account_Role__c>(accRoleList);


    for(Policy__c pol : trigger.new) {
        Account_Role__c accRole = accRoleMap.get(pol.Account_Role__c);
        if(accRole.role_name__c.contains('Duplicate') || accRole.role_name__c.contains('Original')) {
            
            Cust_Alert__c custalert = new Cust_Alert__c(
                Contact__c = accRole.Contact__c,
                Status__c = 'Active'
            );
            CustAlertList.add(custalert);
        }
    }

    insert CustAlertList;
}
```