# Trigger Helper Class Related Contact

Tags: trigger

The trigger helper class below is designed to update a field on a Contact record when that Contact is added to a lookup field on a non-related Account. It will also update a field on the Account related to the Contact.  I have 2 issues I'm struggling with:

1. The code does work to update the Contact, but I am struggling to get the Contact's related Account to update.  The statement I have on line 23 does not return an ID.
2. Overall, the class seems like there could be a better or more simple way to accomplish what I need to do. I am purposely avoiding declarative solutions because there is already a trigger on the Account object and I just want to augment it.

Any help is appreciated!

```
public class AccountUtility {
    public static void updateContactAccountReferredBy(List<Account> newAccountList){
        
        Set<Id> setReferredAdd = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> setReferredAcctAdd = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> setReferredDel = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> setReferredAcctDel = new Set<Id>();
        List<Account> listAccountAdd = new List<Account>();
        List<Contact> listContactAdd = new List<Contact>();
        List<Account> listAccountDel = new List<Account>();
        List<Contact> listContactDel = new List<Contact>();
        
        id oldReferredBy;
        id oldReferredByAccount;
        
        for(Account account : newAccountList){
            Account oldAccount = (Account)Trigger.oldMap.get(account.Id);
                oldReferredBy = oldAccount.Referred_by__c;
                oldReferredByAccount = oldAccount.Referred_by__r.AccountId;

            if((account.Referred_By__c == null && oldAccount.Referred_By__c != null) || account.Referred_by__c != oldAccount.Referred_By__c){
                setReferredAdd.add(account.Referred_by__c);
                setReferredAcctAdd.add(account.Referred_by__r.AccountId);
            }            
            if((account.Referred_By__c == null && oldAccount.Referred_By__c != null) || account.Referred_by__c != oldAccount.Referred_By__c){
                setReferredDel.add(oldReferredBy);
                setReferredAcctDel.add(oldReferredByAccount);
            }
        }

    if(setReferredAdd.size() > 0){
        listContactAdd = [SELECT Id,Referrals__c
                          FROM Contact
                          WHERE Id IN: setReferredAdd];
                for(Contact addReferral :listContactAdd){
                    if(addReferral.Referrals__c == null){
                        addReferral.Referrals__c = 1;
                    }else{
                        addReferral.Referrals__c += 1;
                    }
             }
        update listContactAdd;

        listAccountAdd = [SELECT Id,Referrals__c,(SELECT Id, Referrals__c FROM Account)
                          FROM Account
                          WHERE Id IN: setReferredAcctAdd];
        for(Account addAcctReferral :listAccountAdd){
                    if(addAcctReferral.Referrals__c == null){
                        addAcctReferral.Referrals__c = 1;
                    }else{
                        addAcctReferral.Referrals__c += 1;
                    }
             }
         update listAccountAdd;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Point (1) is covered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318730/why-cant-i-see-related-data-in-my-apex-or-why-are-related-records-showing-up-a)

Comment: By applying the changes from David's comment, you will get an improved solution in your code. I also recommend you to use some framework for your triggers, as [this one](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework) suggested in Trailhead.