# Apex Trigger 'Expression cannot be assigned'

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, contact

I am trying to update the 'Contact Status' value on my Contact object based on the following criteria:

1. Contact Status is currently 'Sales Qualified'
2. Related Opportunity is created within the last year
3. Related Opportunity StageName is 'Quoted'

I am getting two 'Expression cannot be assigned' errors in my Apex Trigger.

```
trigger UpdateContactStatus on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Opportunity OppObj: Trigger.New){
            if(TODAY() - DATEVALUE(OppObj.CreatedDate) <= 365 && 
               OppObj.StageName = 'Quoted' &&
               OppObj.Contact__r.Status__c = 'Sales Qualified')
            {
                OppObj.Contact__r.Status__c = 'Quoted';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need a double equals in `OppObj.StageName == 'Quoted'` since this is Apex not SOQL or formula.

Answer (score 5):

```
           OppObj.StageName = 'Quoted' &&
           OppObj.Contact__r.Status__c = 'Sales Qualified')
```

Comparisons for equality use `==`. `=` is an assignment.

You have more problems here, though.

```
        if(TODAY() - DATEVALUE(OppObj.CreatedDate) <= 365 &&
```

You cannot use formula functions like `TODAY()` and `DATEVALUE()` in Apex code. Look at the [`Date`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) and [`DateTime`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#!) classes to understand how to work with these values in Apex.

```
            OppObj.Contact__r.Status__c = 'Quoted';
```

and

```
           && OppObj.Contact__r.Status__c = 'Sales Qualified')
```

Assigning to a field on a related object in a `before` trigger has no effect. Further, [related records aren't available in a trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318730/why-cant-i-see-related-data-in-my-apex-or-why-are-related-records-showing-up-a) unless you query for them, so your comparison will not work.

You'll have to write a query to get related Contact information (see the link above).

To update, you'll need to construct an actual instance, e.g. via

```
new Contact(
    Id = OppObj.Contact__c,
    Status__c = 'Quoted'
)
```

add that sObject to a `List<Contact>`, and then at the very end of your trigger run an `update` DML operation on that List.

You're also not handling the possibility that `Contact__c` is `null` here; you'll probably want to check for that.