# The trigger is not inserting the field and is not being triggered either

Tags: trigger, update

I built a trigger to insert a custom object record (`NPSResponse__c`) when the SurveyInvitation object is updated. The Developer Consloe did not point out any errors, however when I update a SurveyInvitation record the trigger is not fires.
Can anybody help me?

Here is the code:

```
trigger crianpsresponsetrigger on SurveyInvitation (after insert, after update) {
    if(trigger.isUpdate){
    
    List<NPSResponse__c> NPSResponseList = new List<NPSResponse__c>();

        
        for(SurveyInvitation si : (list<SurveyInvitation>)trigger.new){
            If (si.ResponseStatus == 'Completed' && si.Survey.Name == 'Net Promoter Score'){
                
                List<SurveySubject> SurveySubjectList = new List<SurveySubject>([SELECT SubjectId, Survey.Name FROM SurveySubject WHERE (SubjectEntityType = 'Case' AND SurveyInvitationId =: si.Id)]);
                List<SurveyQuestionResponse> NPSSurveyQuestionResponse = new List<SurveyQuestionResponse>([SELECT Question.QuestionName,ResponseValue,CreatedDate FROM SurveyQuestionResponse WHERE (Question.QuestionType = 'NPS' AND InvitationId =: si.Id)]);
                List<SurveyQuestionResponse> CommentSurveyQuestionResponse = new List<SurveyQuestionResponse>([SELECT Question.QuestionName,ResponseValue,CreatedDate FROM SurveyQuestionResponse WHERE (Question.QuestionType = 'NPS' AND InvitationId =: si.Id)]);

                for(SurveySubject ss : SurveySubjectList){
                    for(SurveyQuestionResponse npssqr : NPSSurveyQuestionResponse){
                        for(SurveyQuestionResponse comsqr : CommentSurveyQuestionResponse){                        
                            NPSResponseList.add(new NPSResponse__c(Survey_Name__c=ss.Survey.Name, Caso_relacionado__c=ss.SubjectId,NPS_Question__c=npssqr.Question.QuestionName,NPS_Response__c=npssqr.ResponseValue,Comment_Question__c=comsqr.Question.QuestionName,Comment__c=comsqr.ResponseValue));
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
                
        insert NPSResponseList;
    }
       
}
```

Comment: See [Why can't I see related data in my Apex, or why are related records showing up as `null`?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318730/why-cant-i-see-related-data-in-my-apex-or-why-are-related-records-showing-up-a). `si.Survey.Name` is `null` because you didn't query it, so your `if` condition is always `false` and the trigger does nothing.

Comment: Refactoring note: You have 3 SOQLs in a single for loop. This trigger will blow up on a SOQL 101 when you have 34 or more SurveyInvitation records updated in bulk.

Comment: Check if your trigger is triggering but not progressing by adding a few system debugs. Log all the values you are checking in IF loop and you shall narrow down the issue.

Comment: @apple123 when I want to make sure my trigger hours a line of code, I often use `System.asset(false);` It makes it super obvious my trigger is indeed executing.