# How to check if a user / owner is active in apex

Tags: apex, user

I am writing an apex trigger handler where I am required to check if the owner (`assigned to` value in a task) is inactive.

```
if (t.OwnerId.isActive == FALSE ) {
        newTask.OwnerId = UserInfo.getProfileId();
} else {
        newTask.OwnerId = t.OwnerId;
}
```

This is what I did so far. You can ignore the else - that is the condition when the owner is active. I am getting an error saying `A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: OwnerId`. How can I check if the id of the owner/user assigned is active or not?

Comment: Seems like that question asker was looking down relationships rather than up.

Comment: N.B. `newTask.OwnerId = UserInfo.getProfileId()` - owners can never be profileIds

Comment: It this context UserInfo.getUserId() must be used insted of UserInfo.getProfileId()

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reference a field on the parent object, the correct syntax is to use the parent relationship name. For standard fields, this means dropping `Id`, so using `t.Owner.IsActive` instead of `t.OwnerId.IsActive`. However, it is context dependent, and you won't be able to read these cross object references off trigger records.

Comment: Regarding trigger contexts, see [this canonical question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318730/why-cant-i-see-related-data-in-my-apex-or-why-are-related-records-showing-up-a) for more solutions.

Comment: When I do this, it won't let me edit the task object anyone. It says "You no longer have permission to change tasks". Is this related to the context?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question.