# Trigger issue on CPQ Group not returning name of product

Tags: trigger, cpq

deep diving into the SF developer world. I am trying to create a CPQ Group for CPQ Quote Lines

This is what I have written so far

```java
trigger QuoteLineTrigger on SBQQ__QuoteLine__c (before insert) {

    for (SBQQ__QuoteLine__c newQuoteLine : Trigger.new){
        
        // If Group on QuoteLine is empty
        If (String.isblank(newQuoteLine.SBQQ__Group__c)){
            
            //Get Product name of QuoteLine
            String findGroupName = newQuoteLine.SBQQ__Product__r.Name;
            system.debug ('hello ' + findGroupName);
            
        } 
    }
}
```

I run this

```
SBQQ__QuoteLine__c  hoc = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(SBQQ__Product__c  = '01t1y000003lBIOAA2', SBQQ__Quote__c = 'a1o1y0000022aYRAAY');

insert hoc;
```

When I debug I get 'hello null'

I thought that if I added the CPQ Quote Line record and I am adding the id of the product2 my trigger should return the name of the product is that not correct?

Thanks

Comment: Related data is not available on records from trigger context variables (`Trigger.new`, `Trigger.newMap`, `Trigger.old`, and `Trigger.oldMap`). You need to gather the product Ids and explicitly query for the products. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318730/why-cant-i-see-related-data-in-my-apex-or-why-are-related-records-showing-up-a for a bit more detail.

Comment: Also, when it comes to formatting code, if you copy/paste your code into the question (or answer), then highlight it, then click the `{}` button (or press ctrl+k), it'll get formatted as a "code block" (i.e. each line starts with at least 4 blank spaces). The alternative is to just use 3 backticks `\`\`\`` on the line before and the line after your code (as I've done for you here).

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. I will try and modify my code.